# how to get notification of mouse going out of components in Java

Tags: java, swing

I am working in application in which i want notification if the mouse has gone out of the JPanel (let's say one of the components) how can this be done ?

Comment: Please read this tutorial : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

Comment: Thanks a lot But I wanted something like Component exit and component kind of notification. I can do it like this by mouse motion listener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way is by implements [MouseMotionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html), another examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/0600__MouseMotionListener.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot reply. But I thought there would be something like Component exit and component enter kind of notification.

Answer (score 1):

Call `addMouseListener` and implement the `MouseListener.mouseExited` method.

Answer (score 0):

override mouseExited method.
http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/128332